# Приведение обьекта в элемент класса в C#

Tags: c#, json, типы

Существует json, возвращаемый с сервера.
Сервер может выдать в нём абсолютно разные объекты, то есть в одном поле может быть как одно значение, так и один объект, и массив объектов.
Я создал класс, примерно такой:

```
[DataContract]
class CustomResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    object obj;
    [DataMember]
    string timestamp;
}
```

Ну и думаю: буду приводить к типу из `obj`

Я использовал простое приведение к типу `(Type)`
Использовал `Convert.ChangeType(customResponse.obj, typeof(Type))`
Но ничего не получается.
Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным

Comment: Может быть вам использовать для каждого значения в `json` отдельный объект и собирать их в массив объектов и массив массивов объектов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не выйдет.

[`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) это некоторый "описатель", который несет в себе информацию о *конкретном* типе. Вы можете его получить вызвав метод [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) у любого объекта или использовав оператор [`typeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof). Сам по себе `Type` это совершенно отдельный класс, со своими полями, который к данным в `obj` никакого отношения не имеет.

Вам же нужен *конкретный* тип к которому вы хотите привести `obj`, а информации о нем у вас в структуре сообщения нет. И сами определить его вы не можете, так как по вашей задумке, тип в `obj` может быть разный.

Вам необходимо либо предоставлять [метаинформацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) о типе, передаваемом в `obj` в том же сообщении (например имя класса) либо не использовать такую структуру передачи данных.

Comment: Спасибо, изменю структуру сервера тогда. Будет возвращать разные классы